# Inserting elements to a Scala mutable Map throws error

Tags: scala, dictionary

I'm trying to insert elements to a mutable Map and as I tried, I got the exception as below:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 62388
 at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.resize(HashTable.scala:255)
 at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.scala$collection$mutable$HashTable$$addEntry0(HashTable.scala:151)
 at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.findOrAddEntry(HashTable.scala:163)
 at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.findOrAddEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
 at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$plus$eq(HashMap.scala:89)
 at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$plus$eq(HashMap.scala:39)
 at test.testMethod(AkkaLoadTest.scala:165)
 at test.testMethod(AkkaLoadTest.scala:27)
 at rait$PriceRequestWorker$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(AkkaLoadTest.scala:224)
 at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
 at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
 at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
 at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
 at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
 at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

It looks strange through! Here is what I do:

```
  var mutableMap= scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]]()
```

I declare the Map globally in my object and in my testMethod, I do the following:

```
if(anotherList.size > 0) {
  mutableMap.get(id) match {
    case Some(entries) => /* Do nothing as the entry is already available in the map */
    case None => {
      mutableMap+= id-> anotherList
    }
  }
}
```

The id is passed as another parameter to the method the above code is implemented. I'm baffled to see the exception that in my sense has got no relevance at all! Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutable collections are not thread safe. Are you by any chance accessing or updating it concurrently from different threads? Given that you say your map is "global", and you use Akka actors, this looks like a recipe for disaster. You should not share state between different actors.

You might try to force synchronize the map via

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val mutableMap = new mutable.HashMap[String, List[String]]
  with mutable.SynchronizedMap[String, List[String]]()
```

If the problem disappears, you know that threading is the issue. You would then rethink your state model; if you really want a shared map and performance with `SynchronizedMap` is too bad, you could try alternatives such as `scala.collection.concurrent.Map`

Comment: Yes, I use Actors. I understand that the exception is caused because of shared state. But I also have another ListBuffer globally and it behaves in a thread safe way and I always get the proper set of elements populated in that global ListBuffer. Why is that?

Comment: @user3102968 You got lucky, that's why.